# To find mean using rolling function only if window has more than x data available

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe df having columns like date, company name, price_standalone, price_consolidated, etc.

I want to find the mean of price column for the past 10 years with one condition.

If price_consolidated has data(i.e. it is not NaN), for the past 10 years then price_consolidated column's data to be used else price_standalone's data to be used.

```
df["Price mean 10 years"] = df.groupby('Company Name')["price_consolidated"].shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=3650).mean()
```

This is how I calculated the mean. Can someone help me with the condition part of the code? 
Also if possible another column next to it stating whether price_consolidated is used of price_standalone is used.

For example, row with datetime index 31-12-2010 will compute mean from price_consolidated from 31-12-2000 to 31-12-2010 if all the data is available else it will compute from price_standalone.

In the image the first occurrence date is already being calculated, so no need to worry about that.
[image: sample output]

Thx.

```
date1 = '31/03/2020'
date2 = '31/03/2010'
date1 = pd.to_datetime(date1)
date2 = pd.to_datetime(date2)
if(df_dates2.iloc[date1, 'First Occurence Consolidated']<date2):
    print(1) #find mean by consolidated data
else:
    print(2) #find mean by standalone data
```

this gives an error of: ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types

Comment: Kindly share sample input data and expected output .

Comment: @Anshul Please check now, thx

Comment: Actually sample data in copy-pastable format, not images. For someone who would want to replicate the scenario locally and test, the images are of little help. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Anshul the csv file is of 105 MB, pls let me know how can I help you, I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Please go through the link I shared

Comment: Actually I am asking you to 'help me' so that I can try 'help you' here ... :D

Comment: @Anshul can you help me solve the error pls?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant - without proper sample input and expected output in the required format. Also, this is an open forum where people try to help each other voluntarily - not liable. I am sure there would be someone else who will be able to help. Thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62149312/finding-10th-percentile-for-all-the-data-cumulatively